# How to map touchpad to screen?

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad

Touchpad shape is more or less like to the screen shape. Isn't there a way to map each position on touchpad to the position of mouse on the screen, so you simply tap at any point on the touchpad and got the mouse in the correspondent position on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VoiceOver's Trackpad Commander does this, although I doubt you can use it without having VoiceOver on. [Here](http://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1137.html) is Apple's tutorial on Trackpad Commander.

Comment: How are gestures connected to mapping trackpad to screen?! All of them just move mouse relative to current position or do something not connected to the mouse position change at all.

Comment: When you touch a spot on your trackpad with Trackpad Commander on, the cursor jumps to that point.

Answer (score 1):

Though there's most likely a programmatic solution to this, there's no baked-in functionality in the system. Though the trackpad does have the same general ratio of the display, it's not an exact 1-to-1 relationship. To test this, drag your finger from one side of the trackpad to the other.

Depending on tracking speed as well as how quickly you dragged your finger, your cursor may or may not make the full trip from one side of the screen to the next.